# Bluehost: Zend Installation, Zend_tool error

Tags: zend-framework, bluehost, zend-tool

I am attempting to run Zend Framework 1.12.1 on my Bluehost web host account.

I am following the example provided via the following link: 
http://www.php-linux.com/home/node/5

- I have created a zf folder in the public_html folder
- I have set an alias for the "zf" with path equal to the bin/zf.sh file
- I have changed permission on the zf.sh file so it can be executed
- I have included a php.ini file in the directory I am attempting to
  create a zf project
- I have generated a php.ini file for PHP 5.3 and set the following

**include_path with added path to zf library folder
**register_argc_argv = On

However, when I attempt to test Zend_Tool by typing:

> zf create project zf1

it gives me notice and then just show the command descriptions as it would when you type "zf"

### Message Display

username@domainname.com [~/public_html/Internship]# zf create project test1

Notice: Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME in /home5/username/public_html/zf/library/Zend/Tool/Framework/Client/Console/ArgumentParser.php on line 128

**Labeled in Red**

An Error Has Occurred
 Action '/home5/username/public_html/zf/bin/zf.php' is not a valid
action.

---

If anyone have any experience with resolving this issue please help and thank you very much in advance.

Best of regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search revealed this: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=4420 which suggests this is a Bluehost-specific problem. There's a hacky fix in there you could try.

However I'm going to say that this shouldn't be an issue, as you shouldn't be using Zend Tool on your production server. It is for code generation, so you should be using this whilst developing apps on your local machine (or development server). What you put on your live hosting should be the finished project.